# when to use spring security- scenario based

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

> Im developing a project in spring mvc which involves two kind of players

1. normal users
2. professionals

registration of users is like any normal standards but registration of professionals is different they have to upload their license etc

the role of users is to login search for professionals and send a message to them 
and the role of professionals is to login and respond to the message.

do i need to implement this using spring security or should i develope in such a way like maintaining a separate table for users and professionals and persist them using hibernate jpa like normal standards.

if i implement using spring security for this scenario what benefit would i get.

to simply put will i gain anything by implementing this scenario in spring security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Security provides a way to protect your Data from unauthorised access by using different Login mechanism.

In plane english **where ever you want user to Login, Spring Security will come in picture**.

For this query

> separate table for users and professionals and persist them using
>   hibernate jpa

This is logic part which you will have to do with or without Spring Security.

**Why use Spring Security?**

Lets say you are not using Spring Security. How will you implement Login logic. You will write a query

```
Select user from User where name="temp" and password="sdfsd";
```

You will get User detail or Null based on Credentials.

- What about session Management??
- What password encryption will you use??
- In future you might want to expose your Login API as Token. How
  will you do that ??
- How will you handling CSRF?? and many more...

You can configure all above points and many more using Spring Security.